# Telegram bot parse user's phone number using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, telegram

I am trying to get a Telegram bot to request a user for his/her number and perform an operation on it.

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|
    case message
    when Telegram::Bot::Types::CallbackQuery
    when Telegram::Bot::Types::Message
      case message.text
      when '/help'
        bot.api.send_message(
          chat_id: message.chat.id, 
          text: 'Display help.' 
          )
      end
      if message.contact.phone_number == "1111111" #undefined method
        bot.api.send_message(
          chat_id: message.chat.id, 
          text: 'Number received.' 
          )
      end
    else
      bot.api.send_message(
        chat_id: message.chat.id, 
        text: 'Unknown command.' 
        )
    end
  end
end
```

I am able to get the Contact object, but how do I access the phone_number field of the object? Using Ruby wrapper for Telegram bots.

Comment: Have you inspected your contact object? What methods does it provide? Have you tried playing with it in irb?

Comment: As per Telegram Bot API, if i removed the 'phone_number == '11111111' portion, I am able to get the text reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by setting a temporal variable to the `Contact` object before querying its `phone_number` field. Not sure if this is the intended interaction, but it works.

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|
    if sender = message.contact #Set a variable to the Contact object.
      if sender.phone_number == "11111111"
        bot.api.send_message(
          chat_id: message.chat.id, 
          text: 'Phone number received.' 
          )
      end
    end
  end
```